# Time with subtraction operation works properly but addition does not

Tags: php

```
// $p_hour_data['p_hour']=02:00:00
// $data['dapr_p_hour']=01:00:00 
// answer is=01:00:00

$total_hour=((strtotime($p_hour_data['p_hour']))-(strtotime($data['dapr_p_hour'])));
echo $total_hour=gmdate("H:i:s", $total_hour);
```

The given code is for subtracting the time the value of the `$p_hour_data['p_hour']=02:00:00` and `$data['dapr_p_hour']=01:00:00`.

It gives the result right `00:01:00`.

But when I change it to addition it gives wrong answer `09:31:44`.

Why it happen like that any solution for time addition operation?

Comment: What does this has to do with `mysql`?

Comment: If working with time, always try to use a timestamp, now you're in the situation that you're trying to calculate hours with a time which has no date associated with it. Also strtotime is not a magician and it will process anything you're trying to pass to it.

Comment: because the data comes from mysql and i want the 2 time data with addition operation that will be pass to mysql database .

Comment: i don't get what you're trying to achieve, what should happen if i add 1.12.2014 and 2.12.2014?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you don't specify the time zone: for instance (using `php -a` interactive mode):

```
> echo gmdate("H:i:s",strtotime('01:00:00'));
00:00:00
```

If you however add `"UTC"` to all time stamps, the correct result shows up.

The reason is that if you don't specify the time zone, PHP will look at the server settings and assume the time is expressed in the time zone specified by the server. This means that `02:00:00` is parsed in Belgium as `01:00:00 UTC`. For subtraction this is not a problem (unless day saving time plays a part as well). For addition however, one needs to have a convention when a day starts. By adding `UTC` however, the time is less ambiguous.

**Example** (using `php -a`):

```
$ php -a
php > echo gmdate("H:i:s\n",strtotime('02:00:00 UTC')+strtotime('01:00:00 UTC'));
03:00:00
php > echo gmdate("H:i:s\n",strtotime('02:00:00 UTC')-strtotime('01:00:00 UTC'));
01:00:00
php > echo gmdate("H:i:s\n",strtotime('02:00:00')-strtotime('01:00:00'));
01:00:00
php > echo gmdate("H:i:s\n",strtotime('02:00:00')+strtotime('01:00:00'));
01:00:00
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is not a timezone issue as `@CommuSoft` mentioned. It's an "integer" overflow value issue.

Taking in mind that [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php#refsect1-function.strtotime-returnvalues) returns a UNIX Timestamp value (a bit large value but still in integers values range for your system), but adding another timestamp value to it (another big value) results to a integer overflow which PHP handles by converting the result to float ; see [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php#language.types.integer.overflow).

```
strtotime('02:00:00'); //int(1419213600)

strtotime('01:00:00'); //int(1419210000)

strtotime('02:00:00') + strtotime('01:00:00'); //float(2838423600)

(int) (strtotime('02:00:00') + strtotime('01:00:00')); //int(-1456543696)

//Values can vary due to different default time zone ;)
```

Once the result passed to `date` function, it will be converted back to `integer` => -145..... (some negative value) and your timestamp is equivalent to `1923-11-05 21:31:44`.

Hope it helps you find out the problem.